# Drupal 7 get Image path in field.tpl.php

Tags: image, templates, drupal-7, field

i'm new in Drupal 7 and would like to know, how to get the image path in my custom field theme.

I have the following in my field--field_image_flow.tpl.php file in my theme folder:

```
<div id="Products" class="ContentFlow" style="overflow: visible;">
<!-- should be place before flow so that contained images will be loaded first -->
<div class="loadIndicator" style="position: relative; top: 150px">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
</div>

<div class="flow" style="position: relative; top: 30px">
    <?php 
        foreach ($items as $delta => $item): 
        print render($item); 
        endforeach; 
    ?>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var productsFlow = new ContentFlow('Products', {
                reflectionHeight: 0,
                scaleFactor: 2.3,
                flowSpeedFactor: 0.15,
                onclickActiveItem: function (item) {
                    var activeItem = productsFlow.getActiveItem();
                    var index = productsFlow.items.indexOf(activeItem);
                    $.fancybox.open([
                        <?php 
                            foreach ($items as $delta => $item): 
                                echo "{";   
                                ?????IMAGEPATH????
                                echo "},"; 
                            endforeach; 
                        ?>
                    ], {
                        padding: 0,
                        index: index ? index : 0
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
</script>
```

How do i get the imagepath out of the $item inside the foreach loop?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the image you can add the image path to the view. Follow the below steps to do this.

1) Add a relationship from the advanced tab towards the right. The relationship should be of fid of the file called for example if the image is field is called Image Test then the relationship to be added is "Content: Image Test:fid"

2) Once you add that you would get a field called File : Path this would add the path to the file. In the settings you need to check "Display download path instead of file storage URI" so that the actual url is displayed.

Now when you come to the template you would get the path instead of the image with the img tag.

Hope that Helps.

Best Regards

Shameem